# How to send notifications from Bot to selected user in MS Teams Bot in Python

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I build a MS teams bot by Bot framework SDK in python language now I want to send notification from bot to user .
I want to send notifications from MS teams Bot to selected user in python without user interaction.

Ex.--> you have pending survey for submission.

Comment: Could you please check proactive messaging - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=python

Comment: I already go through this link but am not getting proper solution in python .can you please suggest anything else ...?

Comment: Please refer these - https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/bot-conversation/python/bots/teams_conversation_bot.py#L191 ,

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/bot-conversation/python/bots/teams_conversation_bot.py#L200 ,

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/bot-conversation/python/bots/teams_conversation_bot.py#L172